# How do I select curve endpoint of multiple segment of curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I know how to select using endpoint selection of a start and end of a curve but cannot figure out if there's multiple segment in the curve....[image]

Comment: You may get better and more detailed answers, if you shared your node setup, your blender file and explained the context in more detail.

Comment: Please clarify: 'can't figure out'  how to do ***what***, if there are multiple splines?

Answer (score 2):

The node `Endpoint Selection` always works on the basis of individual spline segments and therefore selects exactly the points you want to have selected:

[image]

Comment: ... if "multiple" means "all" ;-)

Comment: @AndréZmuda Yes, basically all curves should always be processed with *Geometry Nodes* :D

Answer (score 1):

Every segment gets a new spline ID. So, you could check the spline IDs to distinguish between segments and you could use the *Domain Size* node to count the number of segments which is the *Spline Count*.